# View Pager Current View Selection

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using view pager in my application i have a jump to feature in my application the user can jump to the desired page by selecting some index of grid view.

I  have no idea which method of view pager will select the desired page like in tab host we have a method for this

```
TabHost.setCurrentTab(tabindex);
```

i need some thing like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pager.setCurrentItem(Integer.parseInt(jumpTo_ET.getText().toString())-1);

//pager is your View Pager Object and 
//jumpTo_ET is the EditText object from which you are getting the page index to navigate.
```